# Too many loops problem when loading a file

Tags: python

I would like to reduce the number of for loop when trying to loop into my file.

For example:

```
item =[{"item1": "man", "item2": "many", "item3":"mannyy"}]], [[{"item1": "power", "item2": "cow", "item3":"king"}]], [[{"item1": "man", "item2": "many", "item3":"mannyy"}]], [[{"item1": "power", "item2": "cow", "item3":"king"}]

for i, x in enumerate(item):
       print(x["item1"])
```

I am wondering whether is there a possibility to reduce the number of loop while at the same time could get the enumerate for "i", "ii", "iii" too? I do not wish to use too many for loops

Comment: Well, you could reduce the number of required loops by not having the items wrapped in lists twice. Or just use `print(x[0][0]['item1']` after the first for loop to get the same result without changing the variable `item`.

Comment: But my actual file contains more than the current example. In the i, it has 0-2, in the ii, it has 0-5 while for the iii is has 0-50. That was the reasons why I wanted to find an alternative if possible.

Comment: In that case ... either you change the structure of `item` to reduce the nesting depth or you're stuck with the loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code..

```
item = [{'item2': 'many', 'item1': 'man', 'item3': 'mannyy'},{'item2': 'cow', 'item1': 'power', 'item3': 'king'}, {'item2': 'many', 'item1': 'man', 'item3': 'mannyy'}, {'item2': 'cow', 'item1': 'power', 'item3': 'king'}]


for i in a:
    print(i['item1'])
```

Comment: Is there a way not editing the "item"? Because the actual file contains more than the current example. It is not possible for me to edit the "item"